# Overlapping Dates Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a set of date range where it can either have config values as 'S' or 'D', but the underling date range can have overlap dates and i am trying to get the config values for the respective date.

Note: if the config value is 'D' the date range will be within a data range of another row containing config value 'S' if exists.

Data:

```
Start_DATE       End_Date    Config
01-Jan-2020      31-Jan-2020    S
15-Jan-2020      20-Jan-2020    D
15-Feb-2020      20-Feb-2020    D
01-Mar-2020      20-Mar-2020    S
```

I wanted an output like

```
Start_DATE       End_Date    Config
01-Jan-2020      14-Jan-2020    S
15-Jan-2020      20-Jan-2020    D
16-Jan-2020      31-Jan-2020    S
15-Feb-2020      20-Feb-2020    D
01-Mar-2020      20-Mar-2020    S
```

Tried a number of things, but nothing get this quite correctly for me..

Logic:

1. There can be overlapping Config value 'S' or 'D' on a given date
   range.
2. the Query should extract where for the date range is 'S' or
   'D'

Comment: Please post a couple things you tried (the community understands it not working), and show the actual results, then tell us why the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I write down a solution for only just this one case. As Belayer already told you, you should provide other cases if any and show us what you have tried before. Most probably it will turn into a `CASE WHEN` hell but i hope this solution below gives you some insights.

[Solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14a5fd9c2a9ed692b3f264846b21c13f)

```
WITH MAIN
     AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('01012020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS Start_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('31012020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS End_Date,
                'S' AS config
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('15012020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS Start_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('20012020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS End_Date,
                'D' AS config
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('15022020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS Start_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('20022020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS End_Date,
                'D' AS config
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_DATE ('01032020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS Start_DATE,
                TO_DATE ('20032020', 'DDMMYYYY') AS End_Date,
                'S' AS config
           FROM DUAL
        ),
     MAIN2
     AS (SELECT START_DATE AS DET FROM MAIN
         UNION
         SELECT END_DATE FROM MAIN),
     MAIN3
     AS (SELECT DET AS START_DATE,
                LEAD (DET, 1)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (DET, 'YYYYMM') ORDER BY DET)
                   AS END_DATE,
                  LEAD (DET, 1)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (DET, 'YYYYMM') ORDER BY DET)
                - 1
                   ED2,
                  LEAD (DET, 1)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (DET, 'YYYYMM') ORDER BY DET)
                + 1
                   ED3
           FROM MAIN2),
     MAIN4
     AS (SELECT *
           FROM MAIN3
          WHERE END_DATE IS NOT NULL),
     MAIN5
     AS (SELECT CASE
                   WHEN B.START_DATE IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                      B.START_DATE
                   WHEN     B.START_DATE IS NULL
                        AND LAG (
                               A.START_DATE,
                               1)
                            OVER (
                               PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (A.START_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
                               ORDER BY A.START_DATE)
                               IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                        LAG (
                           A.START_DATE,
                           1)
                        OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (A.START_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
                              ORDER BY A.START_DATE)
                      + 1
                   WHEN     B.START_DATE IS NULL
                        AND LAG (
                               A.START_DATE,
                               1)
                            OVER (
                               PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (A.START_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
                               ORDER BY A.START_DATE)
                               IS NULL
                   THEN
                      A.START_DATE
                END
                   START_DATE,
                CASE
                   WHEN B.END_DATE IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                      B.END_DATE
                   WHEN     B.END_DATE IS NULL
                        AND LEAD (
                               A.END_DATE,
                               1)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (A.END_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
                                  ORDER BY A.START_DATE)
                               IS NOT NULL
                   THEN
                      A.END_DATE - 1
                   WHEN     B.END_DATE IS NULL
                        AND LEAD (
                               A.END_DATE,
                               1)
                            OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR (A.END_DATE, 'YYYYMM')
                                  ORDER BY A.START_DATE)
                               IS NULL
                   THEN
                      A.END_DATE
                END
                   END_DATE,
                B.START_DATE ST,
                B.END_DATE ED,
                CASE WHEN B.CONFIG IS NOT NULL THEN B.CONFIG ELSE 'S' END
                   CONFIG
           FROM MAIN4 A
                LEFT JOIN MAIN B
                   ON B.START_DATE = A.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE = A.END_DATE --AND B.CONFIG='D'
                                                                             )
  SELECT START_DATE, END_DATE, CONFIG
    FROM MAIN5
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]